# How many deaths were there on the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In your average *TOS* episode, at least 1 redshirt dies.  Also, one of McCoy's famous sayings is "He's dead Jim."  That then got me thinking about the following question: **how many deaths of crew members do we know of in *TOS*?**  These need to have occurred during the five year mission that we see and *must* be crew members of the *Enterprise*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 59

That's the number of officer and crewman deaths that [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701%29#Casualties) cites.  So, who were these 59 people?  [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_casualties_%2823rd_century%29#USS_Enterprise_.28NCC-1701.29_casualties) takes care of that as well:

- 9 dead after contact with the galactic barrier ('Where No Man Has Gone Before') | **9**
- Rizzo and three other crewman ('Obsession') | **4**
- 3 died of Rigeliean fever ('Requiem for Methuselah') | **3**
- Elizabeth Dehner, Lee Keslo and Gary Mitchell ('Where No Man Has Gone Before') | **3**
- Barnhart, Darnell, Green, Sturgeon ('The Man Trap') | **4**
- Matthews and Rayburn ('What are little girls made of?') | **2**
- Sam ('Charlie X') | **1**
- Robert Tomlinson ('Balance of Terror') | **1**
- Joe Tormolen ('The Naked Time') | **1**
- Carlisle, three other unidentified redshirts ('The Changeling') | **4**
- Gaetano, Latimer, O'Neill ('The Galileo Seven') | **3**
- Grant ('Friday's Child') | **1**
- Hendorff, Kaplan, Mallory, Marple ('The Apple') | **4**
- Jackson ('Catspaw') | **1**
- Lang, O'Herlihy ('Arena') | **2**
- Karen Tracy ('Wolf in the Fold') | **1**
- Compton ('Wink of an Eye') | **1**
- D'Amato, John B. Watkins, Wyatt ('That Which Survives') | **3**
- Harper ('The Ultimate Computer') | **1**
- Leslie Thompson ('By Any Other Name') | **1**
- Watson ('Elaan of Troyius') | **1**
- Two unidentified crewman ('And the Children Shall Lead') | **2**
- Commodore Decker ('The Doomsday Machine') | **1** (kudos Major Stackings)

That's **53** people who were permanently dead.

Additionally, the following individuals were killed and revived:

- Angela Martine and Leonard McCoy ('Shore Leave') | **2**
- Montgomery Scott ('The Changeling') | **1**
- Pavel Chekov ('Spectre of the Gun') | **1**
- Leslie ('Obsession') and Galloway ('The Omega Glory') - note they died in their respective episodes but were seen in later episodes! | **2**

That's another **6** people, bringing us to a total of **59 deaths (and 6 revivals) under Kirk's command in the five year mission *that we know of*!**  (Decker wasn't under Kirk's command)

Of a [typical crew complement](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class) of 430, that's 13.5% of his crew that died, and 89.7% of those were permanently dead!

Comment: Don't forget Commodore Decker. He commanded the Enterprise. That pretty much makes him part of the crew.

Comment: 'Permanently dead' needs its own category... and it's pretty low considering it's being compared to category, 'has died'.